# Activate button

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic3

I am looking for how make a button like a select in ionic. It can be selected and unselected, the back I know how to do but I don't know how change the style of the button if is checked/unchecked. It will be like this:

[image]

Comment: You can do it via CSS only

Comment: Why don't you use [Segment Buttons](https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/components/segment/SegmentButton/)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for yours answers, finally i did this in the html:

```
<button ion-button [outline]="radioOption.isOutline" (click)="selectButton(radioEmerOptions)">{{radioOption.value}}</button>
```

and in the ts:

```
radioEmerOptions = {value : "L", isOutline : true}    
public selectButton(radioEmerOptions) {
    radioEmerOptions['isOutline'] = !radioEmerOptions['isOutline'];
  }
```